# ui.router state not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router-extras

I am using `ui.router` to detect state change in Angular App. But the controller is not being called on load.

Below is my `app.js` code.

```
 var admin = angular.module('admin',['admin.core']);
    angular.module('admin.core', ['ui.router', 'satellizer', 'ngMaterial']);

    admin.config(function($mdThemingProvider, $stateProvider, 
                          $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider, $locationProvider){
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default').primaryPalette('light-blue', {
        'default': '700',
        'hue-1' : 'A200',
    }).accentPalette('blue');

    // Satellizer configuration that specifies which API route the JWT should be retrieved from
    $authProvider.loginUrl = '/api/authenticate';

    // Redirect to the auth state if any other states are requested other than users
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/admin/login');
    console.log($stateProvider)
    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/admin/login',
            name: 'login',
            controller: 'AuthController as auth',
        })
        .state('users', {
            url: '/admin/users',
            controller: 'UserController as user'
        });
       $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });

    admin.controller('AuthController', AuthController);

    function AuthController($auth, $state, $scope) {
    console.log("Called");
    var vm = this;

    vm.login = function() {
        var credentials = {
            email: vm.email,
            password: vm.password
        }
        console.log(credentials);
        // Use Satellizer's $auth service to login
        $auth.login(credentials).then(function(data) {
            // If login is successful, redirect to the users state
            $state.go('users', {});
        });
    }

  }
```

`AuthController` is not called when my state is `login`.

Comment: why is the url: 'users', not '/users'? and add name: 'users'

Comment: @PiotrPęczek .. corrected

Comment: Do you have `ui-view` somewhere in your root app html?

Comment: Yes. In my master html where app is intialized. I have ui-view there

Comment: check the console for any errors

Comment: no errors at all.. i am all clueless

Comment: Just as info : `ui-router` has the `controllerAs` property. Better to use that. `controller: 'UserController', controllerAs: 'user' ... `

Comment: Can you try something : `.state('login', {
 url: '/admin/login',
 name: 'login',
 controller: function(){ console.log('init login controller') }
})` Is the console message logged?

Comment: @daan.desmedt .. no luck.. nothing in console

Comment: @Gags, can you provide some Fiddle example so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hi @daan.desmedt  .. i think i kind of figured out... when URL is `http://localhost:8001/admin#/login` then it gets the login state but if URL is `http://localhost:8001/admin/login` then there is no state,, how can i handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` you have to provide a base href location. It will parse your state resolve url as `http://localhost:8001/admin/#/login` and should fix your problem.

Try adding `<base href="/" />` to your `<head />` section of your main index file to specify the base path of your application.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider

Also provide a `.htaccess` file on your server to allways redirect the specific request to the mail index page. You **might** have to tweak it a bit to fit your structure.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

> Note that the mod_rewrite had to be enabled on my apache server. By
>   default it was disabled.

Comment: as i am in admin, so my Base URL will be `<base href="/admin" />`  right? And it works only first time.. Means to say that if i visit `http://localhost:8001/admin` then stateprovider makes it `http://localhost:8001/admin/login` but now if i will use refresh then Controller is not called...

Comment: So this fixes your initial problem? Now a new problem is caused upon 'F5' / page refresh? Correct?

Comment: Did you add a `.htaccess ` to your server? See updated answer above.

Comment: i shall place this `.htaccess` in my laravel root directory.. and shall i map this to admin folder?

Comment: Place the .htaccess in the application root directory (your AngularJS application rootdir)

Comment: I have my js files in folder say `a` and view files in folder `b` ... no as such root directory of angularjs... I am using Laravel in PHP

Comment: Just place it in the rootDirectory of the application (project root folder with all subfolders / angularjs files / .... ).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134492/discussion-between-gags-and-daan-desmedt).

Comment: all is working well now... finally :P ... figured out

Comment: I'm very glad for you! Did you adapt your current implementation? Or found the bug? In that case, maybe interesting to share with us :)

Comment: Hi. I have changed approached as we discussed. I have kept header and footer as php templates and loaded html views through ui view and login logout is working nicely. Have you worked with JWT as i have one security concern about changing states through ui router with JWT

Comment: Yeah.  Partyy. But i am really concerned about security. Is JWT secure enough to handle admin panel or we need server side authentication?